# How to decide which source file is used to debug?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am debugging a project that have jar conflicts. There are more than one versions for the same jar (artifact). And at the runtime, only one version is deployed, saying v3. When I set a breakpoint at intellj on v3, it somehow launched v2 of the class file and it stops at incorrect line.

Is there any setting or something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct to be using v3 at runtime? If so, it should be relatively easy to ensure that IntelliJ uses the same dependency - if you are using a build tool like maven, just adjust the `<version>` to v2, or if the libraries are configured manually in IntelliJ, just go into *Project Structure*, add the library v3 (consider removing the library v2) and ensure the module dependes on it correctly.

As for why this happens, at runtime the classloader is "finding" the v3 version of your dependency before, or in exclusion of, v2.

To debug this, you will want to look through any other dependencies and jars you are building into your project, and also at any other jars that are available in the runtime environment (for example, web server "common" or "lib" folder, "endorsed" folders or directories, other deployed applications, etc, etc).

Lastly if you are not already using a build tool like `maven` or `gradle`, this may help to make your dependency management easier.